# Illegal Argument Exception when trying to save an image in Google Drive

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-drive-api

When I try to save a captured image into Google Drive, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
                              at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:48)
                              at com.google.android.gms.auth.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source)
                              at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
                              at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
                              at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:279)
                              at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
                              at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
                              at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
                              at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
                              at com.amrutpatil.makeanote.GDActions.search(GDActions.java:290)
                              at com.amrutpatil.makeanote.GDActions.search(GDActions.java:211)
```

I can successfully sign in and select a folder on Google Drive, however, when I try to save an image, I get the issue above.

I am currently running Marshmallow on a Nexus 6 physical device.

My GDActions.java code:

```
private static ArrayList<GF> search(ArrayList<GF> gfs, com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List qry) throws IOException {
        String npTok = null;
        if (qry != null) do {
            FileList gLst = qry.execute();    //get an error here
            if (gLst != null) {
                for (File gFl : gLst.getItems()) {
                    if (gFl.getLabels().getTrashed()) continue;
                    gfs.add(new GF(gFl.getTitle(), gFl.getId()));
                }
                npTok = gLst.getNextPageToken();
                qry.setPageToken(npTok);
            }
        } while (npTok != null && npTok.length() > 0);
        return gfs;
    }
```

I get an error at FileList gLst = qry.execute() above.

This happens when the search method is invoked here:

```
static ArrayList<GF> search(String prId, String titl, String mime) {
        ArrayList<GF> gfs = new ArrayList<>();
        String qryClause = "'me' in owners and ";
        if (prId != null) qryClause += "'" + prId + "' in parents and ";
        if (titl != null) qryClause += "title = '" + titl + "' and ";
        if (mime != null) qryClause += "mimeType = '" + mime + "' and ";
        qryClause = qryClause.substring(0, qryClause.length() - " and ".length());
        com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List qry = null;
        try {
            qry = mGOOSvc.files().list().setQ(qryClause)
                    .setFields("items(id, labels/trashed, title), nextPageToken");
            gfs = search(gfs, qry);
        } catch (GoogleAuthIOException gaiEx) {
            try {
                gfs = search(gfs, qry);  //Invoked here
            } catch (Exception g) {
                GDUT.le(g);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            GDUT.le(e);
        }
        return gfs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null`.

The "name" it is referring to is the account name. Ensure that you are setting the GoogleAccountCredential object.

```
mAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName("user123@gmail.com");
```

Note: Set the account name as the full email; `user123@gmail.com`, instead of just `user123`.

Comment: I tried setting the account name as you suggested. However, I keep getting the same error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a permissions issue. Although I had GET_ACCOUNTS permission set in my AndroidManifest.xml file, I needed to manually enable Contacts permissions in my app settings.

It may be a device specific issue as I was running my app on a Nexus 6 physical device with Android Marshmallow 6.0.1.

You might want to check you app settings just to be safe.